# Is there a standard notation for this set of numbers

Tags: notation

$$\left\{\frac{K}{3^n} : K\in\mathbb N,\  n\in \mathbb N \right\}$$

Any positive integer divided by any power of $3$.

Comment: Those are the positive elements of the ring $\mathbb Z_3$ obtained by localizing $\mathbb Z$ at the multiplicative set generated by $3$. A sensible notation is therefore $\mathbb Z_3^+$, or something similar.

Comment: Isn't that just the set of positive integers?  Take any integer, multiply by three, and using the resulting number as an input with n=1 will put the original integer into your set.

Comment: (On the other hand, the notation $\mathbb Z_3$ is overloaded —it denotes usually the abelian group $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, the ring of $3$-adic integers, and the localization at $3$ of $\mathbb Z$— so you would in any case have to make explicit what the notation means for you)

Comment: @JasonHise, it *contains* the positive integers, but also $1/3$.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted it as specifying that elements of the set were in N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say a bit about the same set, but with "$\mathbb{N}$" replaced with "$\mathbb{Z}$" (to allow negatives). I would call these the *tryadic rationals* in analogy with the [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).

In terms of notation, they are a [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational#Dual_group), and can be written as $$\lim_{\rightarrow}3^{-i}\mathbb{Z}.$$ I think the notation "$3^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$" would probably be understandable, in a somewhat strained analogy with the notation for the [Prufer groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$.

---

Now, for the nonnegative elements, I would call them the "nonnegative tryadic rationals" - granted, that's not very snappy, but not everything needs to be. In terms of notation, I think replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ would be good: e.g. "$3^{-\infty}\mathbb{N}$" or "$\lim_\rightarrow 3^{-i}\mathbb{N}$."

Comment: His numbers are all positive, though.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Good point, missed that. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

The members of $\displaystyle\left\{\frac{K}{3^n} : K\in\mathbb Z,\  n\in \mathbb N \right\}$ are sometimes called "ternary rational numbers" or "ternary rationals", but I don't know of a standard notation for them besides using that phrase or writing the expression that appears here.  With $K\in\mathbb N$ rather then $K\in\mathbb Z$, I'd call the members "positive ternary rationals".